# Visual C++ should default to lang-cpp

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The default syntax highlighting (prettify) is [now listed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/184109/revisions#) at the bottom of the tag wiki. I noticed that [visual-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b) (go to the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-c%2b%2b/info)) is probably wrong. It is set to use `lang-c` instead of `lang-cpp`.

I understand `lang-cpp` is newer than `lang-c` and this is likely just a historical value based upon [Jeff's original list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/147650), but I think this should be updated to `lang-cpp`.

Comment: *"Microsoft Visual C++ is a C and C++ compiler for Windows."* I suppose they had to pick one.

Comment: Yeah, [originally the C++ tag had `lang-c` syntax highlighting](http://pastebin.com/AWMtu5rK), so this probably just an oversight. Nearly everyone uses MSVC as a C++ compiler. No one writes C89 anymore.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the edits. This started off as a more general question on [meta.se], but I decided it _is still_ clear that per site metas were still the right place to ask/suggest changes to default prettify settings.

Comment: Indeed they are. Just about everything that is on-topic for the über Meta is *also* on-topic here. You don't have to participate both places if your primary or exclusive interest is Stack Overflow. A moderator can migrate any questions that would truly be more appropriate there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems eminently sensible.

I've updated the tag. All new/edited posts will reflect the new syntax highlighting.