# Regex should use lang-regex

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

Similar to my [query about Visual C++](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270901/256431), [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) should default to `lang-regex` instead of `lang-default`.

Comment: Hmm... I just looked at Jeff's original list and [tag:regex] was listed as `[regex] = lang-regex` then; so someone has actually decided `lang-default` was better for regex!

Comment: `lang-regex` does seem to just highlight everything in a single color for regexes. I couldn't find it in the prettify lib either. I'm not so sure it's supported, despite what the FAQ says... I use `lang-none` myself.

Comment: And IMO defaulting to no language for the regex tag is better, because regexes are most often used with a programming language, and that language should be the default (a single regex tag is often indicative of a poor question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lucas got this right [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274639/regex-should-use-lang-regex#comment111733_274639):

> And IMO defaulting to no language for the regex tag is better, because regexes are most often used with a programming language, and that language should be the default (a single regex tag is often indicative of a poor question).

Since Regex questions are *so often* tagged with other languages as well, it doesn't make sense to set an explicit language identifier on that tag. Doing so will cause *all* code in the question to revert to default whenever there is another tag that has a language hint specified, which is quite often. So setting it on that tag would be very detrimental to the overall effects of the syntax highlighter.